# Tags which version of frame work should be merged to single tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, retag-request

I mostly check question related to [codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codeigniter) tag.But there are so many tags related to codeigniter.
Due to which while selecting the tags to answer the question, I have to manually add all the tags to find the related question.

- can we merge all these types of framework version related tags to one for searching question is too repetitive process now
- this can related to other frameworks also

[image: tags related to ci]

Answer (score -2):

All of these tags are valid, separate topics of conversation. But for real-world application, they can pretty much be divided into CI2 and CI3. How these separate sub-functions behave may or may not differ, but I find myself asking more often than not which version of CI the user is trying to implement. The functionality itself is self-evident by the question.